# Python, matching two list's elements

Tags: list, python, element, matching

```
x= [0,2,3,5,6];
y= [64,384,1024,4096,384];
```

The above are two arrays I'm using. Im trying to match the elements together in a pythonic way

example:

if `xType` is 2 i want to compute a variable called `yType` to correspond to its value(position wise) in y. so i should get `y = 384`. if `xType = 3` i should get 1024.

How would i go about doing this

Comment: sounds like you want a dict, see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so short, even Stack Overflow did not allow me to submit such a short answer:

```
y[x.index(2)]
```

This will return element from `y` corresponding to the position of `2` or any other given value from within `x` list.

Hope it helped :)

Ps. Indeed [*dictionaries*](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) may be something you need. Try using them.

Comment: Thanks everyone, This is what i need. But i like the concept of dictionaries and maps also. I will look into them. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

If your specific aim is to generate a `dict` from the two lists you've given, use `zip`:

```
>>> x = [0,2,3,5,6]
>>> y = [64,384,1024,4096,384]
>>> dict(zip(x, y))
{0: 64, 2: 384, 3: 1024, 5: 4096, 6: 384}
```

And get rid of those semicolons!

If you don't need a mapping type, but just want to create pairs of items, `zip` alone will do:

```
>>> zip(x, y)
[(0, 64), (2, 384), (3, 1024), (5, 4096), (6, 384)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the elements in `x` are unique, you can use them as the keys in a [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to lookup the elements in `y` that have the same index. Like this:

```
x = [0,2,3,5,6]
y = [64,384,1024,4096,384]

y_from_x = dict(zip(x,y))

print y_from_x[2] # prints 384
print y_from_x[3] # prints 1024
```

This is useful if you want to do lots of lookups, but if you want to do just one lookup [Tadeck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618578/python-matching-two-lists-elements/6618621#6618621) is more efficient

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {0: 64, 2:384, ...}
```

look up 'maps in python' or something like that

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> xymap = dict(zip(x, y))
>>> xymap[2]
384
```

However, if you also need to lookup elements in x for y, you'll need a `yxmap` as well. And if you need these to be lists for some reason (perhaps because you're modifying them during the course of your program), you could use `i = x.index(2)` and then `y[i]`.